# access to the code of "Mass Email Contacts" componente

Tags: email, contact, massemailmessage

I need to use the "Mass Email Contacts" in custom page. Is it possible I have access to the code of this component salesforce for the selected contacts?

Answer (score 1):

There's a freebie utility called Layout Page that will allow you to convert standard pages to VisualForce. That should allow you to extract the code you're looking for as HTML/VisualForce.